How to download model_index.json from civitai?
I'm new to this area,
I have installed stable diffusion and then downloaded a model from civitai.com
but when i execute, i'm getting error OSError: Error no file named model_index.json found in directory ./model..
Which is expected but I can't find a model_index.json any model i click download, it download the .safetensor only (for example https://civitai.com/models/352581/vixons-pony-styles)
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
import torch

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "./model", torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True
)


prompt = "cat"
image = pipe(prompt).images[0]

image.save("output_image.png")


you can try this:
pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_single_file(pathToSafetensor)
pipeline.save_pretrained(output_dir)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
